# Put an assertion on page title that is coming from a file outside the test

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion

I'm wondering if someone could help with this. I have a file named Titles.js which prints current page title. I have a another AssertTitle.js file in which I get page title from Titles.js file and then trying to assert the title. The code looks like below from both files.

Titles.js file

```
  module.exports = {
  pageTitle: function() {
  let title;
  cy.get('h1').then(function($el) {
  cy.wrap($el);
  title = $el.text();
  console.log(title);
  });
  }
}
```

AssertTitle.js file

```
const titles = require('./Titles')
describe('testing titles', () => {
it('Print title', () => {
   cy.visit("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
   titles.pageTitle();
   expect(title).be.eq("Practice Page");
  });
})
```

The assertion is failing which I understand as it cannot find the title. So I'm looking for some suggestions or workarounds on how to make this assertion work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by replacing "user" with "userName" and adding "instanceName" in cypress.json file. Cypress.json looks like following:

```
  "env": {
  "db": { "userName": "", "password": "", "server": "localhost", "port": 1433, 
  "type": "mssql",
  "options": {
    "instanceName": "",
    "database": "",
    "encrypt": true,
    "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that assertation failing because `title` is not defined in `AssertTitle.js`. From my point of view your code is not following Cypress [best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html).
Which is the reason to use `Titles.js` ? To validate your `h1` is so simple as:

```js
it('validate h1', () => {
  cy.visit("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php")
  cy.get('h1').should('have.text', 'Practice Page')
})
```

If you need to reuse some functions, take a look to [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html).